# How to fix WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed

Tags: jboss

I'm trying to deploy my application, I'm using RED-HAT jboss-eap-7.3. My application.xml is:

The error that i got is :

```
"{
    \"WFLYCTL0080: Failed services\" => {\"jboss.deployment.subunit.\\\"sam-fe-app.ear\\\".\\\"sam-fe-web.war\\\".POST_MODULE\" => \"WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase POST_MODULE of subdeployment \\\"sam-fe-web.war\\\" of deployment \\\"sam-fe-app.ear\\\"
    Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link it/eni/italgas/sam/web/urka/GuiSessionSpacchettatore (Module \\\"deployment.sam-fe-app.ear.sam-fe-web.war\\\" from Service Module Loader): com/sun/rave/web/ui/appbase/AbstractSessionBean\"},
    \"WFLYCTL0412: Required services that are not installed:\" => [
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"sam-fe-app.ear\\\".WeldStartService\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.LogLevelChanger\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.WebUserFacade\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.WebDomainControllerFacade\",
        \"jboss.deployment.subunit.\\\"sam-fe-app.ear\\\".\\\"sam-fe-ejb.jar\\\".beanmanager\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.WebUserdatasourceFacade\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.WebRoleFacade\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.WebDatasourceFacade\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.WebDatasourceUserRoleFacede\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.WebUserroleFacade\",
        \"jboss.deployment.unit.\\\"sam-fe-app.ear\\\".beanmanager\",
        \"jboss.naming.context.java.comp.sam-fe-app.sam-fe-ejb.CheckChangePermission\"
    ],
```

Why this error appears? what I could have forgotten to config and in which file?
I missed some dependencies ? This is not Maven project .

Answer (score 0):

You are getting a java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Failed to link it/eni/italgas/sam/web/urka/GuiSessionSpacchettatore . You need to fix that

Comment: How i can fix, because this class is inside my ear. This is the path: sam-fe-app.ear\sam-fe-web.war\WEB-INF\classes\it\eni\italgas\sam\web\urka\ and here there is class GuiSessionSpacchettatore . thank you

Comment: You are trying to load that class that is in the war it seems with a reference to com/sun/rave/web/ui/appbase/AbstractSessionBean

Comment: Yes this class is GuiSessionSpacchettatore and extend AbstractSessionBean . this jar is appbase.jar .  I dont understand , i've to remove refrrence ? in wich way ? thank you

Comment: AbstractSessionBean is not available to your war classloader, fix that  by using a deployment structure.xml or where your jar is located.

Comment: Hello but i don't know what io have to write inside deployment structure.xml . this class is inside appbase.jar . This jar is inside my APP-INF\lib\ of sam-fe-app project. Realy i dont know ehat have to do ... plase help me